# Как применить плагин jQuery на angularJs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Я еще относительно новичок в JS и AngularJS и столкнулся c такой проблемой. На странице использовал данный плагин https://jqvmap.com/. 
Когда начал добавлять функционал на angularJS, плагин перестал работать. Много где читал, что использование Jquery и Angular не самая лучшая идея. Тогда возникает вопросы: какая альтернатива есть плагинам? есть возможность как-нибудь переделать мой плагин под angular? Или возможно найти похожий плагин на angular? Подскажите как правильно поступить в данной ситуации
Ниже привожу код, все же интересно почему не срабатывает плагин

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="css/jqvmap.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.vmap.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.vmap.world.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({ map: 'world_en' });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<header ng-include="'template/header.html'">
  
</header>

 <ng-view> 
  </ng-view>
  <footer ng-include="'template/footer.html'">
    
  </footer>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>   
    
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```js
var app = angular.module ('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
   templateUrl: 'home.html'
  })
  .when('/company-rates', {
   templateUrl: 'company-rates.html'
  })
});
```

**home.html**

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5 .col-sm-6">
        
        <div class="row">
          <div class="currency-sorting">
          <h1>Want to Send Money?</h1>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>From</label>
              <input type="search" class="form-control"> 
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>To</label>
              <input type="search" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group rate-btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default">Set Rate Alerts</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.location.href='/company-rates.html'">Search Best Rate</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7 .col-sm-6">
        <div class="maps">
          <!-- <img src="img/world.png" alt=""> -->
          <div id="vmap"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так, должно работать:

```
var app = angular.module ('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'home.html'
        })
        .when('/company-rates', {
            templateUrl: 'company-rates.html'
        })
});

app.run(function() {
  angular.element('#vmap').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_en',
  });
})
```

[Пример на Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/G8fr94xty4IU4KSdeG2m?p=preview)